# Changing status bar background and text color in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I am programming my WebView app in android studio and I want dynamically changing the background and text color of the status bar.

I created a JavaScript interface which calls the java function and changed the background to black.

```
getWindow.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

It works well, but I can't change color of text to white. So icons and text are invisible.

Is there any way I can do that? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility
(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.